# RadGrid overrides EntityDataSource Sorting

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, telerik, radgrid

Beforehand:

I'm working with a static Database, which can't be changed, because its used by an external software.

I map the database value from StatusTypeId, if it isn't "1" or "6" to a value which is between these values. 
Background: Supportticketsystem

The Customers should only see the StatusTypeIds 1, 3 and 6. 
1(open), 3(in work), 6(closed)

So i changed the grid values manually and are working now on the correct sorting.

The initial sorting expression, which is executed on the EntityDataSource is working fine, until the sorting function of the grid is used. Then, whether I manually intercepted, the sorting is done incorrectly.

Initial Sorting of EntityDataSource:

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="DefectsDataSource" runat="server" 
ConnectionString="name=*" DefaultContainerName="*" 
EnableFlattening="False" EntitySetName="Defects" Select="it.[DefectId], it.[Name], it.[StatusTypeId]"  
OrderBy="(CASE WHEN it.[StatusTypeId] <> 1 AND it.[StatusTypeId] <> 6 THEN 2 ELSE it.[StatusTypeId] END)"/>
```

It's possible to get the requested sort order from the Grid (SortCommand Event) and set the OrderBy property of the EntityDataSource to sort correctly?
I tried it, but it was ignored.

Implementation of SortCommand Event:

```
    protected void SortCommand(object sender, GridSortCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.SortExpression == "StatusTypeId")
        {
            string sortExpression = (e.NewSortOrder == GridSortOrder.Ascending) ? "ASC" : e.NewSortOrder == GridSortOrder.Descending ? "DESC" : "";
            this.DefectsDataSource.OrderBy = string.Format("(CASE WHEN it.[StatusTypeId] <> 1 AND it.[StatusTypeId] <> 6 THEN 2 ELSE it.[StatusTypeId] END) {0}", sortExpression);
            this.RadGrid.Rebind();
        }
    }
```

I hope there enough informations to help me. If i missed something, please ask me.

Answer (score 0):

i've resolved this Problem, by setting the DataSource from RadGrid manually with ObjectContext.Entity.ToList()[.OrderBy()] and make a manual sorting over reflection and property mapping:

```
public static Dictionary<string, PropertyInfo> ColumnMapper = new Dictionary<string, PropertyInfo>
                                                                   {
                                                                       {"StatusTypeId", typeof(Defects).GetProperty("CustomerStatus*") },
                                                                       {"DefectId", typeof(Defects).GetProperty("DefectId") },
                                                                       {"Name", typeof(Defects).GetProperty("Name") }
                                                                   }; 

* Thats the Custom Column from above.
```

Setting MasterTemplateView.AllowCustomSorting to True and sort on Page_Load() and on SortCommand with following Code:

```
protected new void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var exp = this.RadGrid.MasterTableView.SortExpressions; 
   if (exp.Count == 0)
   {
      this.SortGrid(new GridSortExpression { FieldName = "DefectId", SortOrder = GridSortOrder.Ascending});
   }
   else
   {
      this.SortGrid(exp[0]);
   }
}

protected void SortCommand(object sender, GridSortCommandEventArgs e)
{
    this.SortGrid(new GridSortExpression { FieldName = e.SortExpression, SortOrder = e.NewSortOrder });
}

private void SortGrid(GridSortExpression e)
{
    IOrderedEnumerable<Defects> bindingList = null;
    var defects = DataAccessLayer.GetLoadedSet<Defects>().ToList();
    if (Defects.ColumnMapper.ContainsKey(e.FieldName))
    {
        var prop = Defects.ColumnMapper[e.FieldName];
        switch (e.SortOrder)
        {
        case GridSortOrder.Ascending:
            bindingList = defects.OrderBy(src => prop.GetValue(src, null));
            break;
        case GridSortOrder.Descending:
            bindingList = defects.OrderByDescending(src => prop.GetValue(src, null));
            break;
        case GridSortOrder.None:
            bindingList = defects.OrderBy(src => src.DefectId);
            break;
        }
    }
    this.RadGrid.DataSource = bindingList;
}
```